# Updating JIRA issues from gitlab pipeline

Tags: jira, gitlab-ci, jira-rest-api

I want to move an issue to the deployed stage (transition) when the gitlab pipeline of a merge request has finished. Is that even possible?

---

My Idea so far:

The pipeline is related to that specific issue by both the branch name (see 1.) of the merge request and also the message of that merge request like so "Finish PV-1234".

1. I can parse the issue key from the branch name.
2. I can call a server to run a script making the Jira api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you directly want to close the issu, look into the [gitlab jira integration docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html#closing-jira-issues) - therefore you have to add a description to your MR, to tell the integration to close the issue, as soon as the MR was merged.

If you want more control, write yourself a simple script, that first gets the ids of the available transition (You can get them via `/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions` [see here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue-getTransitions)) and after that posts the transition you want (You can do that by posting on the same endpoint, as the get command mentioned before [see here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue-doTransition)).

Sad that the jira integration doesn't provide more issue-movement than jsut closing issues...

Comment: yeah.. that's stupid. But at least 3 keywords for one state.. Fixes, Closes, Resolves :D

Comment: Do you have access to the IssueId from the GitLab pipeline? If yes where do you get it from? Is it env variable?